# How to do a call from a website to phone number using twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

I am using c# library to make a call to phone number. It gets connected but after few seconds a sound is played and disconnected. I am unable to hear ringing on my head phones

Comment: Are you using the Programmable Voice SDK Quickstart Example? https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/quickstart. Are you dialing the number in E.164 format, https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-e164

Comment: No, I am using the C# SDK for programmable voice and dialing in E.164 format